# Is There a Proper Way to Softcode the Columns for PrimeReact’s Datatable?

Tags: reactjs, primereact

Basically, I built a web app using React that will display data from SQL tables stored on my server. As someone who likes to "dynamize" everything, I made it such that I would store the columns for the tables and then map them into Column components inside the DataTable components.

At first, I had all the columns hardcoded, so whenever I added a new column to one of my SQL tables, I would have to manually add it to my array of columns in my React program as well. I thought softcoding this would be simple as I would just need to take a row of the AxiosInstance containing my SQL data and then gather the row's keys to put into my array of columns to be mapped into Column components. At first, everything seemed fine, but then I noticed that the Column components' filters stopped working for some reason. When I hardcoded the columns, the filters would work, and you can input whatever rules you want. But when I softcoded the columns, the filters would just display the "Clear" and "Apply" buttons, and it wouldn't have the option to input any rules. I checked with console.log() and made sure that both my hardcoded and softcoded columns are of the same type, so I'm not sure why the filters work for the hardcoded columns but not the softcoded ones.

If it helps, here are my states for each React component:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
const [columns, setColumns] = useState([])
```

Here's my useEffect() function:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axiosInstance.get("/path").then((response: any) => {
        setData(response.data)
        setLoading(false)
        setColumns(getColumns(response))
    })
})
```

Here's my getColumns() function:

```
const getColumns = (response: any) => {
    let tempColumns: any = []
    Object.keys(response.data[0]).forEach((key: string) =>
        tempColumns.push({
            field: key,
            header: key,
        })
    )
    return tempColumns
}
```

And here's how I'm mapping the Column components:

```
<DataTable value={data} ...>
    {columns.map((col: any, i: any) => {
        return <Column key={col.field} field={col.field} filter sortable header={col.header} />
    })}
</DataTable>
```

So far, it seems like the only way to have the filters work is to hardcode the columns for each table. They also hardcoded the columns in PrimeReact's documentation when demonstrating how to dynamically map the Column components, so I'm just kinda reaching out there to see if anyone knows how to dynamically set the columns based on the SQL tables as well.